# ADODB connection to a DBF in Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, adodb, dbf

I'm using an Azure WebApp (Tier: F1)

I hosted these files and directories:

```
/wwwroot/default.asp
/wwwroot/Data
/wwwroot/Data/customers.dbf
/wwwroot/Data/vessels.dbf
```

The `default.asp` file contains the following:

```
<%

    On Error Resume Next

    Response.Write("Path: " & Server.MapPath("Data") & "<br>")

    DBRoot = "D:\home\site\wwwroot\Data\"

    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    DataBase = "DRIVER={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;sourcedb="& DBRoot
    conn.Open DataBase

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.Write (Err.Description)
        Response.End 
    End If

%>
```

And i'm getting this output:

> Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\Data 
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I'm not sure if the error is because:

- The driver (Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver) is not installed or supported in Azure
- The path is incorrect (because web apps in Azure have a shared physical path)

**How can I make this connection work?**

Note: just as a reference, I intend to use these dbf files with SQL queries such as this:

```
 <%
    conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [customers.dbf] WHERE userId ='"& userId &"'")
 %>
```

All these used to work in an old hosting I had. It doesn't works in Azure.

Comment: Would love to know if you ever got this working as I have the identical issue

Comment: No, still an issue :( @Petras